# How to recover deleted build definition

Tags: tfs-2015

We are using the "new, scriptable build system" of TFS 2015 and all of a sudden one of our build definitions is gone. It seems that it deleted itself.

Is there a way to undelete/recover a build definition?

Where are the build definitions (those JSON files) acutally stored?

Answer (score 9):

If you are on prem and you just chose delete from the GUI... run this in the TFS database for your specific id:

```
  update Build.tbl_Definition
  set Deleted = 0 --was 1
  where DefinitionId = <your build ID goes here>
```

You will loose your build history without some extra work i did not take the time to dig into, but that might also be do-able.

**NOTE:** You will also loose credentials stored as build parameters you will need to recreate. Might even be best for you to recreate a new build using this as a template to avoid other unknowns.

Comment: The build history can be found under `Build.tbl_Build` with `where DefinitionId = <your build ID goes here>` to filter to see only the specific builds. You want to do the same, as for the definition, `set Deleted = 0 --was 1`

Answer (score 2):

**TFS build definitions are not version controlled items.** So, It's not possible to restore the deleted build definitions for now.

There has been a feature request in uservoice: *[provide a way to version-control build definitions](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2037625-provide-a-way-to-version-control-build-definitions)* According to the response from PM, this is still in process.

> In the new build system coming with TFS 2015 you can see the full
>   history of the changes to your build definition. The feature that is
>   currently missing is the ability to undo or rollback to a previous
>   revision.
>
> We expect to get the rollback deployed to our service in the next few
>   months.
>
> *Chris Patterson*
>
> *Program Manager*

Moreover, the build definitions are stored in the TFS database.

Comment: So basically it's easy to delete definitions and the build history, but an admin task to restore them. It also appears to be difficult/impossible to audit who did what.